# Ant run bat file and go forward

Tags: ant, asynchronous, batch-file, exec

I'm stuck with a stupid problem. The problem is:

I need to start a proprietary self-made server. This server is started using a .bat file (I'm on the Windows OS).

I've wrote an [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) target:

1. `<exec /> start-stupid-server.bat`
2. `<waitfor />` server port.

So the bat file is executed, the server listens for the port. Ant writes BUILD SUCCESSFUL and doesn't quit.
Ant waits until the server window is closed.
I've tried 100,500 ways to overcome it, but I didn't succeed.
Is there a way in Ant to a `<exec />` bat file and forget about it?

`<exec spawn="true" />` doesn't help, because Ant closes the server window and the server shuts down.

I've tried `<exec />` with:

```
start start-stupid-server.bat,
start /b start-stupid-server.bat
```

Nothing helps :( Ant still waits until the server window is closed.

Here is my target:

```
<target name="start_proprietary_server" depends="bootstrap">
    <echo message="going to stop MDM server instance... "/>
    <forget daemon="true">
        <exec executable="${app.custom.root}/bin/stopAll.bat" dir="${app.custom.root}/bin"  />
    </forget>
    <waitfor
            maxwait="20" maxwaitunit="second"
            checkevery="1" checkeveryunit="second" timeoutproperty="mdm.stop.error">
        <and>
            <not> <socket server="localhost" port="12000" /> </not>
            <not> <socket server="localhost" port="14444" /> </not>
        </and>
    </waitfor>

    <if>
        <isset property="mdm.stop.error" />
        <then>
            <echo message="There are some problems while stopping MDM server. See what's went wrong" />
        </then>
        <else>
            <echo message="MDM server successfully stoped." />
        </else>
    </if>

    <echo message="going to start MDM server instance... "/>

    <!--
        Starts but doesn't exit target
        <exec executable="cmd" dir="${app.custom.root}/bin" >
            <arg value="/c start startAll.bat" />
        </exec>
    -->

    <!--
        <forget daemon="true">
            <exec executable="cmd" dir="" >
                <arg value="/c startAll.bat" />
            </exec>
        </forget>
    -->

    <forget daemon="true">
        <exec executable="${app.custom.root}/bin/startAll.bat" dir="${app.custom.root}/bin"  />
    </forget>


    <echo message="Wating for localhost ports #12000 and #14444"/>
    <waitfor
            maxwait="40" maxwaitunit="second"
            checkevery="3" checkeveryunit="second" timeoutproperty="mdm.start.error">
        <and>
            <socket server="localhost" port="12000" />
            <socket server="localhost" port="14444" />
        </and>
    </waitfor>

    <if>
        <isset property="mdm.start.error" />
        <then>
            <echo message="There are some problems while starting MDM server. See what's went wrong" />
        </then>
        <else>
            <echo message="MDM server has been started." />
        </else>
    </if>
</target>
```

Here is the bat file:

```
call .\bcmenv.bat
start /min .\startLocator.bat
sleep 5

start /min .\startServices.bat
exit
```

I've tried to exec it using the `forget` tag, using `start`, `start /b`, and `call`, but nothing helps. Ant doesn't finish the task until the server window is closed.

If I use spawn without `forget`, Ant closes the server window when exiting the target. It uses spawn in conjunction with forget, the Ant target is not finished until the server window is closed.

What can I try next?

Comment: Can you provide more information?  Perhaps seeing your batch file would help.

Comment: Hi Brad. I've added more info about the problem. I've tired: forget, shellscript, exec, call, start... nothing helps. Ant doesn't finish target until proprietary start_server.bat closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make another batch file which starts the server and returns immediately using `start` command:

```
start <path_to_server_bat> <args>
```

Have you tried `spawn=true`?